# DVD Ripper for TV Shows that perferms lookups of episode names

Tags: windows, optical-media, ripping, filenames

I'm looking for an all-in-one solution that is able to take a DVD of a particular TV Show and rip each episode naming them according to this structure: `ShowName - sXXeYY - Optional_Info.ext` where `sXX` is the season number and `eYY` is the episode number. The requirements for this application are:

- Compatible with Windows 10 64bit
- Creates an output file that Plex can read (preferably .mp4)
- All-in-one application (I don't want to use other software to perform lookups of names)

Comment: Are you expecting the software to look-up the information from somewhere online, read the information from the DVD for you or are you prepared to provided the software with a text file giving the season & either all of the episodes or just the season and the first episode on the DVD?

Comment: @SteveBarnes I would like all of the information to be looked up, but if needed, I can give the software the name of the show and the season and it should be able to look up the episode names and pair them with the chapters on the disk.